# EntityFramework calling scaler function throws Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, webapi

I have scaler function `countAbsence` that takes `employeeID` as input

I call it as below

```
int count = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT [dbo].[countAbsence](@employeeID)", employeeID).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I get below exception

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable \"@employeeID\".\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the parameters using  `SqlParameter`.

```
int count = db.Database
              .SqlQuery<int>("SELECT [dbo].[countAbsence](@employeeID)", new SqlParameter("@employeeID", employeeID))
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `countAbsence` is not a table, it's a scalar function. Your proposed query is trying to query a table.

Comment: got it @Flater. I have corrected the post